# How to create an Intermediary table for a M:M database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I have a many-to-many relational database and right now I am at the stage of just getting it set up.

I am using mariadb and have read that when dealing with a M:M then it is a good idea to have a intermediary table to store the relations. I am trying to do that but I am so dumb that I can't figure out the right syntax for creating a column?

```sql
CREATE TABLE doctor_hospitals (
    doctor_id INT FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors(id),
    hospital_id INT FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES hospitals(id)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

above yields the error:

> Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors(id),
>       hospital_id INT FOREIGN KEY ' at line 2

while:

```sql
CREATE TABLE doctor_hospitals (
    FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES hospitals(id)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

yields the error:

> Query 1 ERROR: A table must have at least 1 column

this sorta makes sense. Here is what I am trying to create:

```sql
CREATE TABLE doctors (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    first_names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    medical_number INT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    province VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(20)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE hospitals (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    address1 VARCHAR(75),
    address2 VARCHAR(75),
    phone_number INT,
    country VARCHAR(15),
    province VARCHAR(15),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    zip_code VARCHAR(15)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE doctor_hospitals (
    doctor INT FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors(id),
    hospital INT FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES hospitals(id)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FKs are constraints. You need to define the columns first. Also need to define the indexes for the FKs.

```
CREATE TABLE doctor_hospitals (
    doctor_id INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
    hospital_id INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (doctor_id,hospital_id),
    KEY IX_doctor_hospitals_hospital_id(hospital_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_doctor_hospitals_hospitals FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES hospitals(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_doctor_hospitals_doctors FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors(id)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```